# 502 bad gateway in winginx+nginx

Tags: php, nginx, joomla, winginx

I have joomla 3.x  installation along with few custom component and modules. admin part is working very well but on front side I receive 502 bad gateway error. I check the error log and found the error message given below.

upstream sent invalid header while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: hospital, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"

Appreciate if anybody can help or provide a clue to solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It uses 9054 port, simply edit following files in %WINGNIX%\conf:

- template.vhost
- nginx.conf
- tools-phpmyadmin.conf

Replace port value with:
fastcgi_pass localhost:9054;